# Is there a way I can share my .exe file with images that cannot be extracted?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I created a .exe file with pyinstaller, but it needs to have images that I used in the program to be in the same folder at the time the executable is run. I wish to have privacy to my image because it is my logo. Is there a way I can embed the image in the .exe file so that it is not extracted and the executable runs as if it had no dependence on the logo?

Comment: You are aware that anyone who wants to can just take a screenshot of your logo? Either way, we won't be able to help much unless you clarify *why* the image needs to be next to the executable – how does the code open it?

Comment: I just want to solve the hustle of users copying folders, so that one file instead of a folder is moved and the user can create their own folder if they want.